# How to remove the sit0 network interface?

Tags: networking, ipv6

when I type ifconfig -a, there is a sit0, why it is here, and how to delete it?

```
sit0      Link encap:IPv6-in-IPv4  
          NOARP  MTU:1480  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Answer (score 8):

The `sit0` interface appears if the `sit` kernel module is loaded. To remove it without reboot, unload the `sit` module:

```
sudo modprobe -r sit
```

You may need to make sure all sit tunnels are down and removed before you unload the sit module using

```
ip link set dev <SIT TUNNEL NAME> down
ip tunnel del <SIT TUNNEL NAME>
```

If the module is loaded on startup it will re-appear after a reboot. To remove it permanently see Michael Hampton's answer.

Answer (score 6):

**sit** stands for simple internet transition. **sit0** is the Linux name for 6to4. **6to4** is a tunneling protocol for using IPv6 over an existing IPv4 connection.

Source: http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Linux+IPv6-HOWTO/

To disable sit0 interface

open `/etc/modprobe.d/aliases` file using the command `sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/aliases`
search for "**alias net-pf-10 ipv6**" and replace that with "**alias net-pf-10 off**"

Reboot the machine.

Source: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WebBrowsingSlowIPv6IPv4

Hope this helps.

Comment: This disables IPv6 entirely, not just the `sit` interface.

Answer (score 4):

[Blacklist](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Loadable_Modules#Blacklisting_Modules) the `sit` module, so that it doesn't load.

Edit `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist`:

```
sudo nano -w /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist
```

Add an entry to blacklist `sit`:

```
blacklist sit
```